# Dynamic Creation of Table in EF4 and working with it

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, poco, code-first

Lets say i want to create a table called Customer-orders dynamically like if i want each customer to has its own Table at run-time and then work with it normally in EF4.

i`m using Code-first Approach with POCO.

is that possible in EF4 , any idea how to accomplish that ?

thanks in advance for any tips or info that direct me to accomplish this...

Comment: Sorry for no detail answer, but please refer to the [ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/). It would help with you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you are trying to accomplish here. You want to create table dynamically like at run time and then run queries on that table using EF4?

Answer (score 0):

Name of table is defined by mapping. Basically if you have some code which will provide correct table name to the mapping it should be **theoretically** possible. Practically it is wrong approach. Model must be compiled before it is used by context. In normal scenario the model is compiled only once when the context is first used and then it is internally cached and reused because compiling model is the most performance costly operation in EF (for large models it can take tens seconds) and I think it is also quite large data structure in memory. If you want to change mapping of single table per customer you need special compiled model per each customer and you must use it only for that customer. It will be difficult to handle.